# blues screen after clonning windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, clone, clonezilla

I clone a hard disk of a PC, with clonezilla.

This hard drive was only a partition with Windows XP.
After restore the copy virtualbox but when I boot the OS a blue screen appears saying: `"run chkdsk / F"`.

The run but did not solve the problem.
just install a copy of Windows but I can not run programs that already appear there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question fully. We'll need to know a little more about the partitions and your setup. The blue screen probably also included some other details. (Also, have you done any other research? What have you tried?) Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

this is most likely your boot partition for the VM that is misbehaving.

Boot to OS install media (http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/rconsole.htm#showall):

- Boot to CD
- Press R to enter Recovery Console
- Choose Windows Installation
- Enter Admin Password

When in the recovery console, enter the fixmbr command and the fixboot command separately.  This will eliminate the possibility that its the boot record causing the problem.

Another possibility is a driver/service faultering.  Boot to safe mode to rule this out.  If you can boot to safe mode - uninstall your antivirus, any drivers or hardware services (such as Intel Matrix drivers, NVIDIA update services etc) and any software related to hardware then reboot.

Comment: i tried, but not appear "Press R to enter Recovery Console"